# How to get Id of the top item in ListView at onScroll?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I want to get the `Id` of the top position item of the `ListView` at the time of `onScroll()`.

How should I write the code?

```
public class Isi_Ayat extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.isi_ayat);

        listview....

        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                Toast.makeText(Isi_Ayat.this, "test " + visibleItemCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to output what the onScroll() method passes back to you? Hint: there's a param called 'firstVisibleItem'.

Comment: @Alessio I have tried to return the value zero

Comment: Did you try to output whenever visibleItemCount is not zero, as [comment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) says "(ignore if visibleItemCount == 0)"? Also, maybe worth to check the state at the same time, depending on your needs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by topmost you mean the topmost *visible* item.

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    Toast.makeText(Isi_Ayat.this, "test " + visibleItemCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    int id = ((LinearLayoutManager) listView.getLayoutManager()).findViewByPosition(firstVisibleItem).getId()

}
```

Make sure the LayoutManager is the same you're using for your listview. So for `GridLayoutManager`, change it accordingly.

Comment: @iDeaBrains, my bad, try listView.getLayoutManager() instead of lv.getLayoutManaget()